# regex with urls

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon

I check if a given url matches another one (which can have wildcards).

E.g. I have the following url:

```
john.doe.de/foo
```

I'd now like to check whether the url is valid or not, the user defines the string to check with, e.g:

```
*.doe.de/*
```

That works fine, but with the following it should NOT work but it gets accepted:

```
*.doe.de
```

Here the function i wrote till now, the urls are stored as firefox prefs and i the "checkedLocationsArray" containts all urls to be checked.

```
function checkURLS(index)
{
    if(index >= 0)
    {
    var pos = getPos("URL-Mask");
    var url = tables[index][pos];

    if(url != null && url != "")
    {
        var urlnow = "";
        if(redlist_pref.prefHasUserValue("table.1"))
        {
            var checkedLocationsArray = new Array();
            for(i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
            {
                checkedLocationsArray[i] = tables[i][pos];
            }

            for(i=0;i<checkedLocationsArray.length;i++)
            {
                urlnow = checkedLocationsArray[i];

                if(urlnow == url)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                if(urlnow.indexOf('*.') != -1)
                {
                    while(urlnow.indexOf("*.") != -1)
                        urlnow = urlnow.replace("\*.", "\.[^\.]*");
                }
                if(urlnow.indexOf('.*') != -1)
                {
                    while(urlnow.indexOf(".*") != -1)
                        urlnow = urlnow.replace(".\*", "([^\.]*\.)");
                }
                if(urlnow.indexOf('/*') != -1)
                {
                    while(urlnow.indexOf("/*") != -1)
                        urlnow = urlnow.replace("/*", /\S\+*/)
                }
                else if(url.lastIndexOf('/') != -1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var regex = new RegExp(urlnow);
                var Erg = regex.exec(url);
                if(Erg != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

i think the "else if(url.indexOf('/') != -1)" is the important part. It should work just fine like that, if I alert it I even get that the result is true but it seems like the if is not being executed..
If anything is unclear, please just post a comment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to me you want to anchor the expression with `^...$` (to match the beginning and the end of the string).

Comment: @FelixKling what do you mean with that? All works fine except that the function does not return false if there is no '/*' in the pref and a '/' appears in the url... That has nothing to do with the RegEx, or am I mistaken? As I added, the code "url.lastIndexOf('/') != -1" should be the "problem".

Comment: Well, from my understanding, if you have `*.doe.de` as expression, then you want the URL to end with `de`. In that case, you would add `$` at the end of your expression, to mark the end of the string. For the input you have given, `url.lastIndexOf('/') != -1` would be `false`, so I don't understand your confusion here. Do you want it to match?

Comment: I don't want the url to end with `de`. I justwant to know if there is more after the `de/com/etc.`, e.g. `/foo` if the pref does NOT have /* included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I did the url was not the current url, I changed that below.

I also changed that the * are now replaced with a regular expression and the dots have to be there in this situation.

```
function redlist_checkURLS(index)
{
if(index >= 0)
{
    var pos = getPos("URL-Mask");
    var url = currenturl.replace("http://", "");

    if(url != null && url != "")
    {
        var urlnow = "";
        if(pref.prefHasUserValue("table.1"))
        {
            var urlsok = 0;
            var checkedLocationsArray = new Array();
            for(i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
            {
                checkedLocationsArray[i] = tables[i][pos];
            }

            for(i=0;i<checkedLocationsArray.length;i++)
            {
                urlnow = checkedLocationsArray[i];

                if(urlnow == url)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                if(urlnow.indexOf('*') != -1)
                {
                    while(urlnow.indexOf("*") != -1)
                        urlnow = urlnow.replace("*", "\\S+")
                }

                var regex = new RegExp(urlnow);
                var Erg = regex.exec(url);

                if(Erg != null && Erg == url)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help thought!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the characters for beginning and end of string?

```
function checkURLS(index)
{
    if(index >= 0)
    {
        var pos = getPos("URL-Mask");
        var url = tables[index][pos];

        if(url != null && url != "")
        {
            var urlnow = "";
            if(redlist_pref.prefHasUserValue("table.1"))
            {
                var checkedLocationsArray = new Array();
                for(i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
                {
                    checkedLocationsArray[i] = tables[i][pos];
                }

                for(i=0;i<checkedLocationsArray.length;i++)
                {
                    urlnow = checkedLocationsArray[i];

                    if(urlnow == url)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    //Check there's nothing else in the string
                    urlnow = '^' + urlnow + '$';

                    if(urlnow.indexOf('*') != -1)
                    {
                        while(urlnow.indexOf("*") != -1)
                            urlnow = urlnow.replace("\*", ".*");
                    }
                    else if(urlnow.lastIndexOf('/') != -1)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var regex = new RegExp(urlnow);
                    var Erg = regex.exec(url);
                    if(Erg != null)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that you don't check for the start and the end of the string. Change your code to something like

```
urlnow = '^'+urlnow+'$'; // this is new
var regex = new RegExp(urlnow);
```

`^` is the RegExp code for string-start and `$` the code for string-end. That way you ensure that the whole url has to match the pattern and not only a part of it.